# Multiplication of large number with small number

Tags: matlab, math, numbers, largenumber

I'm trying to compute a rather ugly integral using MATLAB. What I'm having problem with though is a part where I multiply a very big number (>10^300) with a very small number (<10^-300). MATLAB returns 'inf' for this even though it should be in the range of 0-0.0005. This is what I have

```
    besselFunction = @(u)besseli(qb,2*sqrt(lambda*(theta + mu)).*u);
    exponentFuncion = @(u)exp(-u.*(lambda + theta + mu));
```

where qb = 5, lambda = 12, theta = 10, mu = 3. And what I want to find is

```
    besselFunction(u)*exponentFunction(u)
```

for all real values of u. The problem is that whenever u>28 it will be evaluated as 'inf'. I've heared, and tried, to use MATLAB function 'vpa' but it doesn't seem to work well when I want to use functions...

Any tips will be appreciated at this point!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use logarithms.

Let `x = Bessel function of u` and `y = x*exp(-u)` (simpler than your equation, but similar).

Since `log(v*w) = log(v) + log(w)`, then `log(y) = log(x) + log(exp(-u))`

This simplifies to

```
log(y) = log(x) - u
```

This will be better behaved numerically.

The other key will be to *not* evaluate that Bessel function that turns into a large number and passing it to a math function to get the log.  Better to write your own that returns the logarithm of the Bessel function directly.  Look at a reference like Abramowitz and Stegun to try and find one.

Comment: That is indeed the smartest way of doing it!! Thanks! For my need it was however enough to use the symbolic engine which can handle larger numbers. This is how I did it:
    besselFunction = @(u)besseli(qb,2*sqrt(lambda*(theta + mu)).*sym(u));
    exponentFuncion = @(u)exp(-sym(u).*(lambda + theta + mu));
Then
    besselFunction(u)*exponentFunction(u)

will return a symbolic value. You can double() it if you want the double-precision representation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing an integration, consider using [Gauss–Laguerre quadrature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Laguerre_quadrature) instead.  The basic idea is that for equations of the form `exp(-x)*f(x)`, the integral from 0 to inf can be approximated as `sum(w(X).*f(X))` where the values of `X` are the zeros of a Laguerre polynomial and `W(X)` are specific weights (see the Wikipedia article).  Sort of like a very advanced Simpson's rule.  Since your equation already has an `exp(-x)` part, it is particularly suited.

To find the roots of the polynomial, there is a function on MATLAB Central called [LaguerrePoly](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4912-laguerrepoly-m), and from there it is pretty straightforward to compute the weights.